# Which one is correct: "Do you wake at seven?" or "Do you wake up at seven?"

Tags: vocabulary, usage

Someone said to me that the first one is the correct answer, because you use "wake up" to ask someone to stop sleeping. But I think the first one does not sound natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern (American) English, "wake" in your example is *generally* followed by "up". But this isn't always the case.

I don't always like to use NGrams but here's a [helpful image](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wake%20at%2C%20wake%20up%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwake%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwake%20up%20at%3B%2Cc0) that shows the recent trend:

[image: Ngram for wake up vs wake up at]

Of course, this misses some various other phrases that are similar, like the command "wake me at 7 am"... which *is* fine but can also be phrased "wake me up at 7 am".'

[image: Ngram for wake me up at vs wake me at]

So, to answer your question, in **modern** English, "wake up at" is more appropriate and common but "wake at" is not *technically* incorrect... it's simply not much in modern use and you may find pockets where it is still quite acceptable.

Comment: For one kick rectum motivation +1. I always forget to use those comparisons. Maybe unconsciously I don't trust them because I don't understand how they can gather usage frequency from times prior the almighty Internet's entry...

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's the second sentence that's correct and that your friend's misinformed. One could say *Are you awake at seven?* but omitting *up* sounds like *wake* is something one does when one *watches over someone*.

According to [the wisdom of the net](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wake), there are other meanings to the very *to wake* and those use different prepositions. However, the act of entering a conscious state interrupting ones sleep is usually accompanied with *up*.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, *'wake'* is followed by *'up'* when you talk about getting up from a sleep or a nap. And I don't think *'Do you wake at seven?'* is the correct way to ask that. Technically, it is not wrong, but ideally, the latter is a better option. Generally, you *'wake'* and you *'get up'*, which is exactly what *'wake up'* means.